# Struggling with typescript in chat application using socket.io

Tags: reactjs, typescript, socket.io

I am building a real-time notification app using socket.io and typescript and when I am trying to send event from client to server it shows an error. Below is my code when I am updating my state it shows an error in the browser window that "Cannot read properties of null (reading 'emit')"

```
  const [socket, setSocket] = useState<any>(null)

  useEffect(()=>{
    setSocket(io("http://localhost:5000"));
   
  },[])

  useEffect(()=>{
    socket.emit("newUser", user);
  },[socket,user])
```

Comment: That's nothing to do with TypeScript, you explicitly set the null value. Given that it's not actually asynchronous, why use the first useEffect at all?

Comment: Nothing is changed if we put it all in the one useEffect. Still getting the same error. What should I put instead of null?

Comment: Why not the actual socket? Or at least use the right type for the socket state variable, so the compiler can tell you socket.emit isn't safe

Comment: I have tried the actual socket in useEffect to connect to the server and it is working fine but when I am trying to pass socket as a props to other components it shows an error.

Comment: Can you elaborate a little bit more and point me to a right resources. I am actually a beginner

Comment: What error? How are you passing it? Do you reflect everywhere the fact that it's initially null? Have you considered not making it initially null?

Comment: useEffect(()=>{
    const socket = io("http://localhost:5000");
    socket.emit("newUser", user);
  },[user])

Comment: I tried this and it worked but when I am passing socket as a props it shows an red error in a compiler

Comment: In that case socket is only defined inside the useEffect callback, how _could_ you use it anywhere else?

Comment: That's why I was using useState so that I will be able to use socket anywhere else.

Comment: But it didn;t worked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely, your emit fails because you call it too soon, before your connection is established.

```
socket.on("connect", () => {
  console.log(socket.id); // x8WIv7-mJelg7on_ALbx
  socket.emit("hello", { a: "b", c: [] });
});
```

Comment: On the server side I using below code   io.on("connection", (socket: Socket) => {
  socket.on("newUser",(userName)=>{
    addNewUser(userName, socket.id)
  })

Comment: You asked about "Cannot read properties of null (reading 'emit')". Does your code wait for the connection to be established before you send emit?

Comment: I am still getting the same error

Comment: Yes, You are right. It worked. Now I call emit in onClick event of the button to send the user name to the server and It is working fine now. Thanks. Love debugging